# Why dll files must be copied into windows folder in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, dll, installshield, add-on, regasm

I have an interesting problem. Well, I develop an AddOn for an application. My addon is a .NET COM dll and i register it by using regasm.exe (I created a script to register the dll)

The dll requires several dlls but 2 dlls which are xxx.dll and log4net.dll are common, that means other dlls also use these dlls.

I created a setup by using installshield limited version. I copy all dlls to the program files and everything works in Windows 8.

And after I tried to work it on Windows 10, but I got an error which is **"Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies...**"

After that, I made a deep logging and found out, these 2 dlls are needed into Windows folder. when I copy these 2 dlls to the Windows folder, then it works.

So,the same setup file works on Windows 8 but not in Windows 10.

I run the setup file with Admin rights, I cant understand why it is like that. Why the application looks the dll files under Windows folder in Windows 10?

Is there any config or? 
I created 2 setup files for now. The setup for windows 10, it copies externally 2 dlls into windows

Comment: Are you sure you haven't those files in your windows directory on your Windows 8?

Comment: yes I am sure, I checked now also, there are no dlls in the windows folder in windows 8

Comment: See if these two dlls are being loaded from GAC in windows 8, not from local program files folder.

Comment: its a good point but I checked also there, there is not these dlls. I checked under win\assembly and win\ms.net\assembly..

Comment: No not like that. Open resource monitor and select your process, now in loaded modules, find out the dlls path.

Comment: I think i found out the problem. I tried in windows 8. I deleted one of these dll and i checked the log, the application is looking for the dll under windows folder. So in Windows 10, it cant find the dlls in program files folder then it checks window folder.

Comment: log4net should be in GAC. for xxx.dll you should check.